# Pandas not saving to csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv file that I am just pivoting using pandas and then trying to save as a csv.  I have never had a problem doing this before, and it is pretty simple so I have no idea whats happening.  One thing that I did change is I am using Anaconda and before I used the 64 bit version and now I switched to 32 bit, but I can't imagine this should be the issue...the code executes but no file is saved.

This is the full code I am using:

```
import pandas as pd

#read file
df=pd.read_csv(r'D:\Sheyenne\mcleod_prcp_orig.csv')
df=df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
df=df[(df.Year >= 1984) & (df.Year <= 2012)]
#pivot table
prcp=pd.pivot_table(df, values='PrcpIn',
                        index=['Year', 'Month'],
                        columns='Day')

prcp.to_csv=(r'C:\Users\Stefano\Documents\Documents\2015 Summer RA\nan_count.csv')
```

Comment: is it failing silently? Did you try changing the target folder to c:\ (or something similar)?

Comment: Yes failing silently, I have tried 3 or four different directories and same thing.  Maybe I should uninstall and reinstall anaconda

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to remove "=" from your last line

write

```
prcp.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Stefano\Documents\Documents\2015 Summer RA\nan_count.csv')
```

instead of

```
prcp.to_csv=(r'C:\Users\Stefano\Documents\Documents\2015 Summer RA\nan_count.csv')
```

The latter binds the `to_csv` attribute of `prcp` to the string path of the csv (i.e., it's equivalent to  `prcp.to_csv = r'C:\Users...'`)

Comment: oh my gosh.  I can't believe I just did that.

Comment: This comment made me smile :)